# How do I minimize the runtime of a parallelized computation?

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, parallel-processing

Assume that there is a function `f` that determines the results of a set of `n` [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) computations, and immediately terminates upon finding the answer to the last problem. Each of the `n` processes takes some non-negligable amount of time unique to that process, and there is a perfect linear correlation between time spent on a computation and work done during that computation.

In more math-y terms, every `i`th parallelized subproblem `n_i` takes time `t_i` to terminate, and each `t_i` is unique to each parallelized subproblem.

Given those conditions and an infinite number of processors, it is easy to see that the total runtime of the algorithm is exactly `max(t)`. However, the computers people program on have a bounded number of processors `p`, after which introducing any more subprocesses overwhelms the realistic system and actually increases the total running time of `f`.

My question is - given this practical scenario where the number of subprocesses is bounded by `p` - what is the fastest algorithm that can determine how to optimally schedule the set of parallelized subproblems `n` across the `p` processors in order to minimize the total runtime of the function `f`?

Comment: Sounds like the bin packing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stark's comment about the bin packing problem, I found that this problem actually has a name! It's called, quite sensibly, the [Multiprocessor Scheduling Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling). As I suspected, it's in NP, which means there's no efficient algorithm for solving it. That's quite unfortunate news in the context of the application I'm programming at the moment, but useful to know nonetheless!